# Jquery address: unable to handle incoming deeplinks?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-address

I am using this plugin with AJAX based loading on my page, which handles everything pretty well to be honest, except when i try to catch incoming links that do not have a hash fragment in them.

**Address Bar**
incoming link-> hostname.com/path/
user navigates to another ajax state-> hostname.com **/path/** #hash
Here i am expecting the plugin not to include the path into the address bar because the hash is representing this.

**AJAX GET**
incoming link-> hostname.com/path/
user navigates to another ajax state-> hostname.com/path/
The actual request **does** load the correct state.

is there any way to have it not add the path to the address bar?
e.g 
hostname/#web-development
instead of:
hostname/web-development/#web-development

**Click handling**

> $('a.internalLink').live('click', function(event) {
>       event.preventDefault();
>       clickedLink = $(this);
>       $.address.value(clickedLink.attr('href').replace(base,''));
>   });

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the event of the anchor tag being clicked on, and prevent the default action occuring using [event.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$(document).delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
    var targetHref = this.href;

    window.location.href = targetHref; // or whatever

    event.preventDefault(); // stop the page changing.
});
```

You may also be interested in the new HTML 5 additions, which allow manipulation of the browser history; i.e you can use AJAX to update the page, but still changing the the address. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) for more details (Mozilla Developer Center).

Comment: hi thanks for your help, i have this piece of code already in place:<br />$('a.internalLink').live('click', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault();<br />
  clickedLink = $(this);<br />
  $.address.value(clickedLink.attr('href').replace(base,''));<br />})

Comment: i've updated my question with my method of preventing the default event.

Answer (score 0):

I have circumvented the problem by redirecting any unhashed URLS to the hashed equivalent as such:

> ```
> if(!window.location.hash){
>   window.location.href = 'http://'+window.location.host+'/#'+window.location.pathname+window.location.search;
> };
> ```

It's not that elegant, maybe there's a better solution, but it works.